# Accessing string array resources in an activity

Tags: android

I have following code in my main Activity.

```
private List<Notes> chap = new ArrayList<>();
Resources res = getResources();
String[] chap1Titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.Introductiontitles);
String[] chap1Notes = res.getStringArray(R.array.Introductionnotes);
private void initializeData(){
chap.add(new Notes(chap1Titles[0],chap1Notes[0]));
chap.add(new Notes(chap1Titles[1],chap1Notes[1]));
}
```

In Android Studio it does not give any error for this code.But when I launch Activity it's display nothing and     gets stopped. When I changed this code as follows it worked. I am not understanding the problem with above code.

```
private List<Notes> chap = new ArrayList<>();
private void initializeData(){
chap.add(new Notes("Introduction ","About Introduction topic"));
chap.add(new Notes("Motion ","About Motion topic")); }
```

**Logcat:**

04-11 18:16:30.150 24035-24035/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-11 18:16:30.290 24035-24035/? D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication:com.ilearn.itemdetail
04-11 18:16:30.300 24035-24035/? D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
04-11 18:16:30.300 24035-24035/com.ilearn.itemdetail D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
04-11 18:16:30.370 24035-24035/com.ilearn.itemdetail D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-11 18:16:30.370 24035-24035/com.ilearn.itemdetail W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415e3d58)
04-11 18:16:30.380 24035-24035/com.ilearn.itemdetail E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.ilearn.itemdetail, PID: 24035
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ilearn.itemdetail/com.ilearn.itemdetail.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2126)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
                                                                           at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
                                                                           at com.ilearn.itemdetail.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:23)
                                                                           at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Can you post your logcat here

Comment: Sorry but I don't have it now

Comment: press Alt+6 in android studio you will get the logcats

Comment: Yes I will post it later as I do not have my PC with me now.

Comment: @Kokatesk , everything is looking fine in your code , just make sure that you have put values inside the string array (Introductiontitles,Introductionnotes) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
private List<Notes> chap = new ArrayList<>();
Resources res = getResources();
String[] chap1Titles;
String[] chap1Notes;
private void initializeData() {
  chap1Titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.Introductiontitles);
  chap1Notes = res.getStringArray(R.array.Introductionnotes);
  chap.add(new Notes(chap1Titles[0],chap1Notes[0]));
  chap.add(new Notes(chap1Titles[1],chap1Notes[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are initialized something wrong. Please write code in this way and try again:

```
private List<Notes> chap = new ArrayList<>();
String[] chap1Titles;
String[] chap1Notes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeData();
}

private void initializeData() {
    chap1Titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Introductiontitles);
    chap1Notes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Introductionnotes);
    chap.add(new Notes(chap1Titles[0], chap1Notes[0]));
    chap.add(new Notes(chap1Titles[1], chap1Notes[1]));
}
```